# Jekyll site redirects list

Tags: redirect, rubygems, jekyll, config, github-pages

I'm building a site with Jekyll. It seems like there's no inbuilt way to define a list of redirects (I want a list of links to redirect to the same place, but with `/wiki` as the prefix).

There is a plugin called [`jekyll-redirect-from`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from), but when installing that and adding a `redirects.json` with my required redirects, it still didn't work. I still get a 404 when visiting those sites, rather than getting redirected. And no, rebuilding the site doesn't help.

Is there a way of specifiying (in the latest version of Jekyll, preferably in `_config.yml`) that `/x, /y and /z` should redirect to `/wiki/x, /wiki/y and /wiki/z`? I've seen a bunch of Github threads purporting to deal with this, but they (nor the `jekyll-redirect-from` plugin) seem to solve my issue

Comment: [This blog post](https://adam.garrett-harris.com/how-to-redirect-pages-in-jekyll/) has a few options that may work for you. If the `jekyll-redirect-from` plugin isn't functioning, Option 2 would be a relatively easy implementation.

Comment: @LukeH I ended up making a folder with an `.md` file for each redirect I needed, and each file had a `permalink` and `redirect_to` in the front matter using the plugin. Technically works, but I'll check the article to see if there's a better way. Cheers